# How to convert the simpleproducts plugin of impresspages into a booking plugin

Tags: impresspages

I need ton convert the simpleproducts plugin of Impresspages onto a simple booking plugin. The only requirement is to add a check-in and check-out field to the simpleproductcheckout page. On submit of this simpleproductcheckout form, an email to send to the website owner.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

just have a look at the source and modify to your needs. Or write a more detailsed specification and ask someone from the community to do those modifications for you if you feel it is too complicated.